# why the width is not increasing on an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following code:

it increase the width of an element as well as decrease it.

```
 function _width(ele, size, speed){
    ele = document.getElementById(ele);
    var eleWidth = ele.clientWidth,

        incInWidth = setInterval(function(){

            if (eleWidth<size) { increase();};
            if (eleWidth>size) { decrease();};
            if (eleWidth=size) { stopInc();};
        }, speed),

        increase = function(){
            ele.style.width = eleWidth + ' px';
            eleWidth++;
        },

        decrease = function(){
            ele.style.width = eleWidth + ' px';
            eleWidth--;
        },

        stopInc =function(){
            clearInterval(incInWidth);
        };
};
```

when i run this code on google console then this function returns `undefined`. And there is not error because it doesn't throw any error and this function is not functioning.

it does not add any style attribute to the that element which is passed to the above function. what that mean is, it is not calling `increase();`, `decrease` or `stopInc();` sub-functions  at all or if it does then it is not evaluating the first statement in these three sub-functions.

i think it should work because its more simpler code runs perfectly but it only increase the width:

```
function c (e,s,v){
    var ele = document.getElementById(e),
    width= ele.clientWidth;

    var incInWidthOfEle = setInterval(function(){

            if (width <= s) {
                    increase();
                }else{
                    stop_();
                };

            }, v);   

    var increase = function(){

            ele.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + width +'px;');
            width++ ;
    };

    var stop_ = function(){

        clearInterval(incInWidthOfEle);

    };

};
```

i had just added some more features in the first code than the second one and if the second code runs perfectly using `setInterval`, then using this ideology, i am not mistaking in the first code in the matter of using `setInterval`.

so where is the mistake?

Comment: 'size' is not used in the first method, shouldn't it be ?

Comment: sorry it is typing mistake.. thanks for that

Comment: `if (eleWidth=size)` Wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please get us your example call. You probably mistake in this code:

```
if (eleWidth < size) { increase();};
if (eleWidth > size) { decrease();};
if (eleWidth == size) { stopInc();};
```

**EDIT:
Full solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/2cfdj6z2/

Comment: Use comments to ask about details, not separate answers.

Comment: I can't because I dont have 50 reputation.

Comment: Then just be patient and answer something else :)

Comment: Just delete your 'solution'. You've duplicated the author's error in line 3 of your snippet. Hint: = != ==

Comment: Because I quote his code? You are only criticize but don't give an answer or help for him...

Comment: noo... he is right. i got to know my mistake. i used assignment operator not the comparing operators